# How to generate unit test coverage when using command line flags in Golang subprocess testing?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have unit tests for most of our code. But I cannot figure out how to generate unit tests coverage for certain code in main() in main package.

The main function is pretty simple. It is basically a select block. It reads flags, then either call another function/execute something, or simply print help on screen. However, if commandline options are not set correctly, it will exit with various error codes. Hence, the need for sub-process testing.

I tried sub-process testing technique but modified code so that it include flag for coverage:

```
cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "-test.run=TestMain -test.coverprofile=/vagrant/ucover/coverage2.out")
```

Here is original code: https://talks.golang.org/2014/testing.slide#23
Explanation of above slide: http://youtu.be/ndmB0bj7eyw?t=47m16s

But it doesn't generate cover profile. I haven't been able to figure out why not. It does generate cover profile for main process executing tests, but any code executed in sub-process, of course, is not marked as executed.

I try to achieve as much code coverage as possible. I am not sure if I am missing something or if there is an easier way to do this. Or if it is just not possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Amer

Comment: This is shadowed in search engine results by a not so relevant [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412908/how-do-i-unit-test-command-line-flags-in-go). Please consider amending the title to include `unit test command line flags in Go`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would factor the logic that needs to be tested out of `main()`:

```
func main() {
    start(os.Args)
}

func start(args []string) {
    // old main() logic
}
```

This way you can unit-test `start()` without mutating `os.Args`.

Comment: Thank you! I was so focused on making sub process testing work that didn't think about re-factoring. What we will do is move all os.Exit() calls in a wrapper function. That way we can just mock that function in tests.

Answer (score 6):

I went with another approach which didn't involve refactoring main(): see [this commit](https://github.com/VonC/gogitolite/commit/f656a9858cb7e948213db9564a9120097252b429):

I use a global (unexported) variable:

```
var args []string
```

And then in `main()`, I use `os.Args` unless the private `var args` was set:

```
a := os.Args[1:]
if args != nil {
    a = args
}
flag.CommandLine.Parse(a)
```

In my test, I can set the parameters I want:

```
args = []string{"-v", "-audit", "_tests/p1/conf/gitolite.conf"}
main()
```

And I still achieve a 100% code coverage, even over `main()`.

Comment: You solved the next problem I was about to have. So far I was setting flags in unit tests using: `flag.BoolVar(SHOWVERSION, "SHOWVERSION", true, "usage")`. It works as long as I don't redefine to test flag with a different value. Thanks, I will be using your approach.

Comment: @Amer Yes, I always set flags in `main()`. I only set `args` in test.

Comment: Using this with Go 1.11, I found I had to reset flag.CommandLine on each test redefining the flags, to avoid a "flag redefined" panic.:
```lang-go
 for _, check := range checks {
  t.Run("flagging " + check.arg, func(t *testing.T) {
   flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(cmd, flag.ContinueOnError)
   args = []string{check.arg}
   main()
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @VonC solution with Go 1.11, I found I had to reset flag.CommandLine on each test redefining the flags, to avoid a "flag redefined" panic.:

```go
    for _, check := range checks {
        t.Run("flagging " + check.arg, func(t *testing.T) {
            flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(cmd, flag.ContinueOnError)
            args = []string{check.arg}
            main()
        })
    }
```

Comment: @VonC using NewFlagSet also enables you to use `SetOutput`, as in `flag.CommandLine.SetOutput(someBuffer)`, in order to catch stderr output in your tests and check correctness for sad cases too.